# Multiply list of lists with elements of multiplier list Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matrix

I want to multiply the lists below with the elements of a multiplier list. So that multiplier[0] multiplies the first list in list of lists, multiplier[1] multiplies the second list in list of lists etc.

Thank you!

I have tried this so far:

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(multiplier,list_of_lists)]
```

This is the list of lists:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 0, 1]]
```

Multiplier list:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried as of now?

Comment: `res = [[item * mul for item, mul in zip(sub_l, mul_l)] for sub_l in src]`

Comment: There is no code we could help fixing in your question. Read [ask] and provice a [mre]. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner changed it, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll convert your code from list comprehension into simple loop, you will see where problem is:

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(multiplier, list_of_lists):
    result.append(a * b)  # appends a copies of list b
```

It's definitely not what you're trying to do. You need nested loop to iterate over items of inner lists:

```
result = []
for multiplier, sub_list in zip(multipliers, list_of_lists):
    new_list = []
    for item in sub_list:
        new_list.append(multiplier * item)
    result.append(new_list)
```

Or you can write it shorter using nested list comprehension (*you can give variables shorter names to look more "compact"*):

```
result = [[multiplier * item for item in sub_list] for multiplier, sub_list in zip(multipliers, list_of_lists)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (****edit: see caveats in comments**** )?

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], 
[1, 0, 0, 0], 
[1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 2, 0, 1]])
a2 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376])
res = (a1.T*a2).T
```

Comment: Using external packages for such as simple calculations could be too much.

Comment: I do agree. Yet normally the code is not in a vacuum and we import it either way in our project. Also, I think your solution is missing transpose.

Comment: Solution suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension for a more compact implementation.

```
multi_list = [[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1],    [1, 2, 0, 1]]
mul = [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]

new_List = [[i * b for i in a] for a, b in zip(multi_list, mul)]

print(new_List)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check something like this:

```
list_of_lists = [[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 1]]

multiplier_list =  [1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]
output_list = [[x * multiplier_list[i] for x in list_] for i, list_ in enumerate(list_of_lists)]

print(output_list)
# [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
#  [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
#  [0.41503749927884376, 0.8300749985576875, 0.0, 0.41503749927884376]]
```